# Proving the differentiability and continuity of $ f(t)=\frac{1}{it(b-a)}(e^{itb}-e^{ita})$ extended by $f(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Proving the differentiability of: $$ f(t)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{it(b-a)}(e^{itb}-e^{ita}),&t\neq0 \\ 1, &t= 0 \end{cases}$$

This is the characteristic function of  $\mathcal U(a,b)$ and the professor mentioned something about proving it's differentiability, and I wanted to know how, or if anyone could do it?

Comment: Formulas in titles are good, but should not be tall.

Comment: Hint: Write a power series for $f(t)$.